# sql server query - is writing multiple queries the only way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table of fruits:

`FruitId ColorId NumofPurchased`.

I want to return a row for each of the colorId's where NumOfPurchased is max for that colorId.  I am coming up with approaches like looping through the colorId's or manually write 10 queries for 10 colors ... I don't know, is there a better/more optimized way to do this?

I am using SQL Server 2008 express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want (whether it's the max for each colour across all fruit, or the max for each colour per fruit) - but you can change/add values to the `PARTITION BY` clause if necessary.

```
;with fruitCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  FruitId, ColorId, NumofPurchased,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColorId,
                               ORDER BY NumofPurchased DESC
                              ) AS rn
    FROM    fruit
)
SELECT FruitId, ColorId, NumofPurchased,
FROM fruitCTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(NumOfPurchased), ColorId, FruitId
FROM fruit
GROUP BY ColorId, FruitId
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I need fruitid too in the select clause, which will break the code because it's not in the group by clause or anything.

Comment: Edited my answer to include this column.

Comment: then it will list all the fruits in the result (I just checked)! I  want to select the fruit with max numberofpurchased per each color.

Comment: That's a different set of requirements than what you originally stated in the question. You could try removing ColorId from the SELECT to see how that affects your resultset.